# Issue with my site not processing payment subscriptions

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I am going through a bootcamp right now on learning web development using cloud 9 ide and Ruby on Rails. I have imported the gem for Stripe. And I have set up my JavaScript for taking the credit card information and sending it to Stripe then have Stripe send back a Customer token to Rails server for record with the email account used on signup. However when I go to test it out the payment never goes through. It processes the request and creates a new user for the site but when I go to stripe's webpage there are no transactions.

Here is my code:

```
/* global $, Stripe */
//Document ready.
$(document).on('turbolinks:load', function(){
  var theForm = $('#pro_form');
  var submitBtn = $('#form-signup-btn');
  //Set Stripe public key.
  Stripe.setPublishableKey( $('meta[name="stripe-key"]').attr('content') );
  //When user clicks form submit btn,
  submitBtn.click(function(event){
    //prevent default submission behavior.
    event.preventDefault();
    submitBtn.val("Processing").prop('disabled', true);
    //Collect the credit card fields.
    var ccNum = $('#card_number').val(),
        cvcNum = $('#card_code').val(),
        expMonth = $('#card_month').val(),
        expYear = $('#card_year').val();
    //Use Stripe JS library to check for card errors.
    var error = false;
    //Validate card number.
    if(!Stripe.card.validateCardNumber(ccNum)) {
      error = true;
      alert('The credit card number appears to be invalid');
    }
    //Validate CVC number.
    if(!Stripe.card.validateCVC(cvcNum)) {
      error = true;
      alert('The CVC number appears to be invalid');
    }
    //Validate expiration date.
    if(!Stripe.card.validateExpiry(expMonth, expYear)) {
      error = true;
      alert('The expiration date appears to be invalid');
    }
    if (error) {
      //If there are card errors, don't send to Stripe.
      submitBtn.prop('disabled', false).val("Sign Up");
    } else {
      //Send the card info to Stripe.
      Stripe.createToken({
        number: ccNum,
        cvc: cvcNum,
        exp_month: expMonth,
        exp_year: expYear
      }, stripeResponseHandler);
    }
    return false;
  });
  //Stripe will return a card token.
  function stripeResponseHandler(status, response) {
    //Get the token from the response.
    var token = response.id;
    //Inject the card token in a hidden field.
    theForm.append( $('<input type="hidden" name="user[stripe_card_token]">').val(token) );
    //Submit form to our Rails app.
    theForm.get(0).submit();
  }
});
```

I do not receive any kind of error so I am unsure what the issue is. If you need to see my other files of code please let me know which ones and I will post them. 
Thanks for all the help.

Comment: This code only creates the stripe card token (https://stripe.com/docs/api/ruby#create_card_token), not a customer, or a charge. Do you create the charge in your Rails code somewhere?

Comment: There should be. Would you happen to know what file it would be under? I have tried to go back through the videos I have for this course but nothing has fixed it.

Comment: According to the course videos. The JavaScript code is supposed to hijack the sign up button and send the card field to Stripe then Stripe will send back a card field. Mine however is not doing that.

Comment: I don't know which exact video you got, and have no idea about what controller you may hit, as I don't see the form target (should be in your template file)
You can debug this using the console on chrome (ctrl + shift + C), and see if the browser makes the call to Stripe, or in your case, if there's an before the send attempt.

Comment: Okay. I will see what I can find.